# The content from pagination returns empty

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Using PagingAndSortingRepository the content returns with {} and right number of content from page url parameter. Example: My table has 20 rows and in url a put ?page=0&size=10. When returns in the postman the key content return

```
    "content": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
```

Debuging the request and return it has values. But is not showing. Don't know why.

my repository

```
public interface LocalUtilRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LocalUtilModel, Integer> {
    Page<LocalUtilModel> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Spring boot version

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
```

The result from request

```
{
    "content": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "totalPages": 2,
    "totalElements": 11,
    "last": false,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 10,
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

My model

```
   @Entity(name = "EXPLOCALUTIL")
public class LocalUtilModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DESCLOCALUTIL")
    private String descLocalUtil;

    @Column(name = "COORD")
    private String coordenada;

    private String referencia;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "IDEXPFEIRA")
    private Integer idExpFeira;
}
```

Comment: data is coming but its empty. try debuging a bit.

Comment: I done it. But, in debug,  the ResponseEntity.ok().body( localUtilRepository.findAll(pageable)) has the values in the content.

Comment: `ResponseEntity.ok().body( localUtilRepository.findAll(pageable))` is returnig data then there is problem in parsing it. are you using __Postman__ or browser to hit rest end point?

Comment: I'm using postman. I read about and maybe it be the Jackson. But the spring has the all jackson implementations in this version. I've tried using the annotation @JsonIdentityInfo. But still not working

Comment: it looks like your `LocalUtilModel` class is not serialized properly. please post this class' code and your serialization configuration

Comment: I Found the error. I'm using lombok and made a mistake. The problem is that i forgot to annotate it with @Data. I didn't see the problem because get de objects with right values in ReponseEntity.Thanks to all of you and i apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to annotate with `@Data` in model class because I'm using `lombok`.

Comment: The problem is setters and getters not being present on the model

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON response it is showing like`"offset":0`.

Try to pass this in your repository pageable parameter.

`PageRequest.of(0, 10)` here 0 is the page number and 10 is offset.

**Formula definition:**

```
int start = pageNumber * offset + 1;

int end = start+offset.
```

So in our scenario the start will be 1 and end will 10.
This will fetch the top 10 returns.

`ResponseEntity.ok().body( localUtilRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 10))`

Just pass your page in first Param and size in second Param.

Comment: as he commented above, he is getting data through service call.

Comment: Localutil model data was not presented in that JSON.